# Adding Edittext value

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to get text and add to the sqlite with button.However when I clicked the button,State) {

Comment: Show us the main activity code

Comment: put the code of your sqlite helper class here to better help

Comment: I added @okset .

Comment: What?? There's nothing here.

Answer (score 0):

It has added the data and then it turns back to MainActivity. Please check if the data is added again.